# I installed a ssl after that the image slider not working

Tags: image, ssl, slider

Hello after installing a ssl on my site the image slider has stopped working.

The site isnt woedpress its just a php site thats quite old.

I installed the ssl through namecheaps cpannel & turned the redirect http to https on.

https://www.compare-travel-deals.com/ - my site

http://www.travelsite2.epizy.com/ - how it shold look

I've gone through changing any links i find to http: to https:

Viewing the source i thort it was somthing to do with this line ""  but can work out where the link is to change http to https.

Hopefully someone knows.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> this was the line i forgot to put in above. ""

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind i scanned through the index.php and found the link to the http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js file and changed it to https. And it works now, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have also came across similar issue on my website's home page.
When I accessed my website from http to https(means after addition SSL) my image slider stopped working.

I tried below workaround:-
replaced all http links on my home page with https.
I assume in this case all http link should have respective https links available.

After that my image slider started working same like earlier it's working with http.